# MSSQL Nodejs module throws invalid time in execution of a stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, database, node.js, stored-procedures

I've setup a nodejs server which provides an api to my mssql server.
I'm trying to execute a stored procedure of my mssql database in nodejs which inserts some data into one of my tables. I've got an input with the type 'sql.Time' which has the value '11:20:13'. Even tho the sql.Time Type requires sth like 'hh:mm:ss' which is the case, the mssql module in nodejs throws an error saying:

```
error: RequestError: Validation failed for parameter 'erreichbar_von'. Invalid time.
```

This is the testdata: http://hastebin.com/xucomefizo.pl

This is the log: http://hastebin.com/mubezuweca.sm

I hope somebody can help me out with this problem since I'm out of ideas.

With best regards,
Tak3r07

Comment: Are you able to fix this problem? I am also facing this and could not resolved it. Please share any thoughts if you fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this error while working on a rest api for my sql server. I ended up having to pass the time as an ISO string instead of as `"12:00"`. In javascript I used `(new Date()).toISOString();` to produce `"2020-02-18T04:32:23.019Z"`